# Wireless issues on new 15.04 install

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04

I have recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 after having been forced to use windows for about a year.  Unfortunately my laptop is having some pretty severe wifi issues since the switch. I suspect it is a driver issue of some sort, but I am certainly not an expert when it comes to anything of this nature.

I connect fine to the network, however my speeds are about 1/3 to 1/2 what they were on windows and the connection has a huge amount of jitter and packet loss type problems.  An example would be that I cannot use any video streaming type of applications since it will go from playing HD video without problems to suddenly buffering every 5 seconds on SD.

I have included the output from the "wireless_script" that seems to be popular on here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  This is driving me crazy

Edit: the script output was too large for this post, [so here is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5iOMl8RdwCHZkc0NURFVHlyRlE/view?usp=sharing)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Apr 2015 22:56 CEST +0200

Booted last: 29 Apr 2015 18:42 CEST +0200

Script from: 06 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-15-generic #15-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 16 23:32:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 73)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:572a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 046d:c048 Logitech, Inc. G9 Laser Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f3:0060 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                278528  0 
mac80211              720896  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               196608  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              540672  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    20480  0 
ideapad_laptop         20480  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 ideapad_laptop

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.178.32  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2a02:8071:a85:9400:5cab:4822:2968:35ac/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2a02:8071:a85:9400:e8b:fdff:fecb:55f7/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::e8b:fdff:fecb:55f7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1266569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:465501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1495432302 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:62002254 (62.0 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:20  Invalid misc:3677   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search fritz.box

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 7260 (Wireless-N 7260)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.19.0-15-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               25.15.12.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:02:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlan0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       f5f94749-d8be-4a76-a7c9-1fd5ea07637e
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     54 Mb/s
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   f5f94749-d8be-4a76-a7c9-1fd5ea07637e | FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.178.32/24, gw = 192.168.178.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.178.1
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.178.32
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.178.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 756000
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 432000
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       domain_name = fritz.box
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1431204145
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.178.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       next_server = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       ntp_servers = 192.168.178.1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 864000
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 2a02:8071:a85:9400:e8b:fdff:fecb:55f7/64, gw = fe80::2665:11ff:fe28:ce24
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         ip = 2a02:8071:a85:9400:5cab:4822:2968:35ac/64, gw = fe80::2665:11ff:fe28:ce24
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         ip = fe80::e8b:fdff:fecb:55f7/64, gw = fe80::2665:11ff:fe28:ce24

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off

SSID                       BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Criblan                    <MAC 'Criblan' [AC2]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
o2-WLAN40                  <MAC 'o2-WLAN40' [AC6]>  Infra  4     2427 MHz  54 Mbit/s  62      ▂▄▆_  WPA2       no        
Alice-WLANX5               <MAC 'Alice-WLANX5' [AC4]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  59      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  no        
FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7390    <MAC 'FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7390' [AC3]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
--                         <MAC '\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00' [AC7]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  50      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
o2-WLAN50                  <MAC 'o2-WLAN50' [AC5]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  49      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
UPC3215117                 <MAC 'UPC3215117' [AC9]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Boardingstudio Heidelberg  <MAC 'Boardingstudio Heidelberg' [AN8]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
UPC2177030                 <MAC 'UPC2177030' [AC8]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
ALICE-WLAN80               <MAC 'ALICE-WLAN80' [AN10]>  Infra  4     2427 MHz  54 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA1       no        
FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable       <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable' [AC1]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  60      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2  yes     * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam]] (600 root)
[ipv6] method=auto
[connection] id=eduroam | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=eduroam | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[802-1x] ca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/Deutsche_Telekom_Root_CA_2.pem
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UNI-HEIDELBERG]] (600 root)
[connection] id=UNI-HEIDELBERG | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=UNI-HEIDELBERG | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/UNI-WEBACCESS]] (600 root)
[connection] id=UNI-WEBACCESS | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=UNI-WEBACCESS | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable]] (600 root)
[connection] id=FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable | type=wifi
[wifi] ssid=FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=ignore

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5350 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5470 - 5725 @ 40), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (57240 - 65880 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      5   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=49/70  Signal level=-61 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FRITZ!Box 6340 Cable"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000054b885a71b
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'Criblan' [AC2]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Criblan"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000091371307
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC 'FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7390' [AC3]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=40/70  Signal level=-70 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"FRITZ!Box Fon WLAN 7390"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000086b0b965b7e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC 'Alice-WLANX5' [AC4]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Alice-WLANX5"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001652f7bf9f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC 'o2-WLAN50' [AC5]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"o2-WLAN50"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000001d0eb2d5f29
                    Extra: Last beacon: 816ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 06 - Address: <MAC 'o2-WLAN40' [AC6]>
                    Channel:4
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Quality=46/70  Signal level=-64 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"o2-WLAN40"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000004defaad8c18
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 07 - Address: <MAC '\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00' [AC7]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000e310e8235
                    Extra: Last beacon: 672ms ago

 050C020300000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 08 - Address: <MAC 'UPC2177030' [AC8]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=33/70  Signal level=-77 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC2177030"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000588ed0ec0
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 09 - Address: <MAC 'UPC3215117' [AC9]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=39/70  Signal level=-71 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"UPC3215117"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000098d88f17
                    Extra: Last beacon: 84ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. I have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes are ineffective, I will edit my answer to add additional steps.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick so far!  I'll let you know if there are any other problems, but it is already working MUCH better

thanks!